# Manage database connections with zend

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

A friend of mine uses zend and he is confused over how you should manage the database connections. What is the standard way to do it with zend?

Any snippets with the typical setup using for example **MySQL**?

I saw something called `zend-db`, any guide with snippets for dummies there?

Answer (score 0):

well you saw zend-db right ? then you can use it's adapter to manage your database connections.

it's simple and easy !

you just have to create a PDO adapter once in your application to connect with the databse, then you can use that adapter every time you  want to communicate to database,

here is the snippet

```
resources.db.adapter = "Pdo_Mysql"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.params.host = "HOST-NAME"
resources.db.params.username = "USER-NAME"
resources.db.params.password = "PASSWORD"
resources.db.params.dbname = "DATABASE NAME"
```

you just put your code in application.ini file make neccessary changes like hotname, username and password and put your database name which you want to connect.

i assume you are using zend framework version <= 1.12 .

anyway it's simple in all the versions ..

also take a look,

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.html